# Get color of text string in UI testing

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm trying to assert that the color of my text is what it should be, and am struggling to do so. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aidfz.png) is a picture of the table in my app. I'm just trying to get the color of "requested" (gray) or "draft" (orange). I was trying to access the label which is the actual string of "requested" or "draft" and then get its color, but can't find any color options.

```
var timeSheetStatusColor = app.tables.element.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).staticTexts.elementBoundByIndex(1).label
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you want the `UIColor` value or the English word for the corresponding `UIColor` value?

Comment: Whichever one would make the assert(timeSheetColor == orange color) to true? I am completely new to this, not very sure. So far, my assert is looking like
    XCTAssertTrue(timeSheetStatusColor == UIColor.orangeColor())